# Why trigger and click do not work in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that does:

```
$('td.unique').live('click', function () {  
//function logic here  
});
```

This works fine on I click on the td of my table. All fine!
Now I would like to be able to have the same functionality programatically in certain cases without the user actually pressing click.
I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                                                                                                              

    $(".clearButton").click( function () {                                                                                                                                
        var username = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"][name="uname"]').val();                                                                                     
        var user_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('label').val();                                                                                                             

        var input = [];                                                                                                                                                    
        input[0] = {action:'reset', id:user_id,user:username,};                                                                                                                 
        $.ajax({                                                                                                                                                            
            url: 'updateprofile.html',                                                                                                                               
            data:{'user_options':JSON.stringify(input)},                                                                                                                     
            type: 'POST',    
            dataType: 'json',                                                                                                                                               
            success: function (res) {                                                                                                                                        
                if (res.status >= 1) {                                                                                                                                       
                    //all ok                                                                                                                                                
                    console.log("ALL OK");                                                                                                                               
                     $(this).closest('tr').find('.unique').trigger('click');  
          $(this).closest('tr').find('td.unique').trigger('click');  
          $(this).closest('tr').find('td.unique').click();  


                }                                                                                                                                                           
                else {                                                                                                                                                      
                    alert('failed');                                                                                                                                        
                }                                                                                                                                                           
            }                                                                                                                                                               
        });
```

This button is in the same row that the `td.unique` is

None of these work. Why? Am I doing it wrong? Is the function that I have bind in live not taken into account when I click this way?

Comment: If you provide your HTML source, or an example of it, it will help people to answer your question.

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." - https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: which element is referred to as `this` here ??? and also show your markup (html)

Comment: Please post HTML, and what is "this" referring to?

Comment: @TusharGupta:Updated OP

Comment: @Jim add a sample of the html please

Comment: I am going to guess the issue is the $(this) in the ajax call, I don't think it is referring to the button any more. Try caching $(this) then using it in the ajax function. I am not an ajax expert

Comment: @Huangism:Yes!!!Caching the row worked!!!Added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cache the $(this) inside the ajax function.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

the $(this) inside the ajax function will not refer to the element that is clicked

```
$(".clearButton").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var username = $this.closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"][name="uname"]').val();
    var user_id = $this.closest('tr').find('label').val();
    var input = [];

    input[0] = {
       action: 'reset',
       id: user_id,
       user: username,
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'updateprofile.html',
        data: {
            'user_options': JSON.stringify(input)
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.status >= 1) {
                console.log("ALL OK");
                $this.closest('tr').find('.unique').trigger('click');
                $this.closest('tr').find('td.unique').trigger('click');
                $this.closest('tr').find('td.unique').click();
            } else {
                alert('failed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In other cases it is not needed.I am not sure why it matters now.But it works so +1

Comment: It matters in this case because the $(this) is inside the success function of the ajax call. If you are using a lot of $(this), it is always a good idea to cache it so jquery does not need to keep making$9this) every time. At work, if we use something more than once, we will cache it to reduce overhead